# How to make a non-interpolate string interpolate in Perl

Tags: perl

How can I make the string below interpolate once it's determined that it has a '$' in it?

```
use strict;

my $yrs;
my $stg = 'He is $yrs years old.';

if ($stg =~ /[@#\$\%\/]/) {

    print "Matched dollar sign.\n";
    $yrs = '4';
    
} else {

    print "No Match.\n";

}

print "Year's scalar: $yrs\n";
print $stg . "\n";
```

I get:

```
He is $yrs years old.
```

I would like to get:

```
He is 4 years old.
```

Comment: See also [String::Interpolate](https://metacpan.org/pod/String::Interpolate) and [Is it possible to have interpolated variables when a string is read from a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57812884/2173773)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to write a template system. There are plenty of those around, so you don't have to go to through the trouble of writing your own.

```perl
use Template qw( );

my $template = 'He is [% years %] years old.';

my $vars = {
   years => 4,
};

my $tt = Template->new();
$tt->process(\$template, $vars, \my $output)
   or die($tt->error());

say $output;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably write that with `sprintf`:

```
my $template = 'He is %d years old.';
my $output = sprintf $template, $years;
```